# Adding a coordinate label tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to label coordinates as such. For example, I want to put the text "(1,0)" next to the coordinate point (1,0). I've been looking at the nodes documentation - is there a better way to do it?   Here is the figure I have drawn, for reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
\draw (0,0) -- (8,8);
\draw (0,2) -- (6,8); % line from (0,1/4) to (3/4,1)
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (8.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {$v_1$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,8.5) node[anchor=south east] {$v_2$};
\fill[black!40!white] (0,2) -- (6,8) -- (0,8) -- cycle;
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(0,1)} node:{$(0,1)$}{}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. The last line of your `tikzpicture` cannot work, `\addplot` is defined by `pgfplots` (which you don't load), and only works inside an `axis` environment (which you don't have, or seem to need). And the `:` after `node` shouldn't be there. Do you just want `\node[below] at (1,0) {$(1,0)$};`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was my first attempt. It wasn't working, hence my problem! THanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, than you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
\draw (0,0) -- (8,8);
\draw (0,2) -- (6,8); % line from (0,1/4) to (3/4,1)
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (8.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {$v_1$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,8.5) node[anchor=south east] {$v_2$};
\fill[black!40!white] (0,2) -- (6,8) -- (0,8) -- cycle;
\node[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=red,label=left:{$(0,1)$}] at (0,1) {};% this replace your `addplot`
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: `addplot` is `pgfplots` macro and cannot be used in a `tikzpicture` unless you don't include it in a axis environment (your MWE can not be compiled).

If you like to labeled some other coordinates, the possible solution is for example:

```
\coordinate[label=left:{(0,2)}] (A) at (0,2);
\coordinate[label=above:{(6,8)}] (B) at (6,8);
\draw[fill=black!40!white] (A) -- (B) -| (A);
```

by which you can replace:

```
\draw (0,2) -- (6,8); % line from (0,1/4) to (3/4,1)
\fill[black!40!white] (0,2) -- (6,8) -- (0,8) -- cycle;
```

in your MWE. Another alternative can be, for example:

```
\draw (0,2) node[left] {(0,1)} -- (6,8) node[above] {(6,8)}; % line from (0,1/4) to (3/4,1)
```

etc.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, done.